# SQL-How to get last 7 days data,display 0 when there is no record for specific day

Tags: sql

```
22-03-2016  0   0   15  15
23-03-2016  1   2   12  15
24-03-2016  0   1   15  16
25-03-2016  0   1   9   10
26-03-2016  0   0   1   1
28-03-2016  0   0   13  13
29-03-2016  0   0   17  17
30-03-2016  0   1   19  20
31-03-2016  0   1   10  11
```

there is no data for 27,I want 0,0,0 if there is no data.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily be done using `generate_series()` in Postgres

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a calendar table and left join with your source table

```
select c,date,s.coalesce(s.col1,0) as col1,
coalesce(s.col2,0) as col2 ,coalesce(s.col3,0) as col3 

from calendar as c 
left join source_table as s on c.date=s.date
```

Comment: You could add first and last date (e.g. max/min from source_table.)